# Get back to correct page with a back link when using pagination

Tags: pagination

First of all, excuse my poor english... i hope you will get it :)

I have a page that contains a list of entries titles. There a lot of entries so i use pagination to display them.

When you click on an entry, it goes to a page dedicated to the entry and there is some js that may add hashtags to the url. On that page i also have a back link that is supposed to bring you back to the precedent page.

How can i send the user back to the correct paginated page ?

i can't use history.back() because of the hashtags. so i would like to retrieve the "index" of the entry to calculate the correct pagination page... is that possible ? how ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about javascript, not EECMS.

Comment: @RobsonSobral When I read the question, I read that he's asking for a non-JS solution.

Comment: yes..a non js solution...somethin like :
{exp:channel:entries channel="gammes" category="{segment_2_category_id}" orderby="title" sort="asc"}
         {if segment_3 == url_title}
          {if count > 0 && count<9}
           page 1
          {/if}
          {if count > 9 && count<18}
           page 2
          {/if}
          {if count > 18 && count<27}
           page 3
          {/if}
         {/if}
        {/exp:channel:entries}

but more 'universal'

Comment: @Anna_MediaGirl, he can still move back to a [specific point of the history using JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). `history.back()` isn't the only option. `history.go(-1)`, `history.go(-2)` can be used too. Every time a JS adds a fragment identifier to the URL, an integer can be saved on a variable and used to know how many points the pagination page are back on history.